# Outputting multiple lines of text in R Shiny using renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

**MY PROBLEM**

I have a dataframe with multiple rows, each of them containing a short narrative in various sentences and a code associated to each narrative.

I'm designing a Shiny app where users select one of the narratives and they see the narrative on the main panel. I'm using `htmlOutput()` in the `ui.R file` and `renderUI()` in the `server.R` file.

My problem is that I can't find a way to get the output in multiple lines. I can only get all the sentences together, as a paragraph (like below):

```
"she was in Florida over the break. she went to the beach. I don't know why she did that, but she liked it. she saw a couple alligators."
```

However, this is what I actually want:

```
"she was in Florida over the break."
"she went to the beach."
"I don't know why she did that, but she liked it."
"she saw a couple alligators."
...
```

**WHAT I TRIED**

I have read that I can call the `HTML()` function to add a break after each sentence using `paste()`. But if I do that, then I get no output on the main panel when I select a narrative.

This is what I tried doing (see the HTML call at the bottom):

```
output$Full_text = renderUI({
    my_text = my_df %>%
      filter(narrative_code == input$selected_narrative)
      pull(narrative_text)})
    my_sentences = unlist(strsplit(my_text, "(?<=(\\.|\\?)\\s)", perl = TRUE))
    HTML(for(sentence in my_sentences){
      paste(sentence, '<br/>')})
```

It works when I run it in my console, but not when I run my app, so I guess the problem has to do with how to output the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paste`'s `collapse` argument instead of the for-loop:

```
library(shiny)

my_sentences <- LETTERS

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("myText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myText <- renderUI({
    HTML(paste0(my_sentences, collapse = "<br>"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```